# How to enable managed response header policy of SecurityHeaders with CloudFrontWebDistribution in AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have a  `CloudFrontWebDistribution` in my AWS CDK infrastructure code in typescript:

```js
const cloudFrontDistribution = new cloudfront.CloudFrontWebDistribution(this, 'distribution', {
            originConfigs: [
                {
                    s3OriginSource: {
                        s3BucketSource: webBucket,
                        originAccessIdentity: originAccessIdentity,
                    },
                    behaviors : [ {
                        isDefaultBehavior: true,
                        defaultTtl: Duration.seconds(1),
                        lambdaFunctionAssociations: [
                            {
                                eventType: LambdaEdgeEventType.VIEWER_REQUEST,
                                lambdaFunction: midwayEdgeFunction.currentVersion,
                            },
                        ]
                    },
                    ]
                }
            ],
            defaultRootObject: 'index.html',
            viewerCertificate: cloudfront.ViewerCertificate.fromAcmCertificate(props.certificate, {
                aliases: [props.stageProps.cloud_front_domain_name],
                sslMethod: cloudfront.SSLMethod.SNI,
                securityPolicy: cloudfront.SecurityPolicyProtocol.TLS_V1_2_2019
            }),
            viewerProtocolPolicy: cloudfront.ViewerProtocolPolicy.HTTPS_ONLY,
            loggingConfig: {
                bucket: logBucket,
                includeCookies: true,
                prefix: 'cflogs/'
            }
        });
```

I want to enable Security Headers managed policy ([see here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-managed-response-headers-policies.html#managed-response-headers-policies-security)) to this distribution. However I only see aws cdk documentation for doing so for a `Distribution` object, but not for a `CloudFrontWebDistribution` object.

How to enable managed response headers policy of Security Headers to a `CloudFrontWebDistribution` object in AWS CDK?

Answer (score 5):

Get an [escape hatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html) reference to the underlying L1 `CfnDistribution` construct.  Then, manually set the `ResponseHeadersPolicyId` property on [DefaultCacheBehavior](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-defaultcachebehavior.html#cfn-cloudfront-distribution-defaultcachebehavior-responseheaderspolicyid), making use of the [ResponseHeadersPolicy.SECURITY_HEADERS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_cloudfront.ResponseHeadersPolicy.html#static-security_headers) static method:

```js
const cfnDistribution = cloudFrontDistribution.node.defaultChild as cloudfront.CfnDistribution;

cfnDistribution.addPropertyOverride(
  'DistributionConfig.DefaultCacheBehavior.ResponseHeadersPolicyId',
  cloudfront.ResponseHeadersPolicy.SECURITY_HEADERS.responseHeadersPolicyId
);
```